# Deletando uma imagem no formulario

Tags: laravel, imagem

Preciso deletar uma imagem por vez do meu banco, tenho uma tabela `n:m` e não estou conseguindo deletar a imagem.

Segue parte do método para deletar a imagem.

```
public function deleteImg(Imagem $imagem)
{
    $imagem()->delete();
    \Session::flash('mensagem_sucesso_produtos','Imagem deletada!');
    return back();
}
```

Comment: O que acontece? como está enviando as variáveis para exclusão? falta contexto.

Comment: Minha route está assim:
` Route::delete('produtos/deletar/{produto}/{imagem}','ProdutosController@deleteImg');`
e a ação do botão está:
 `<a href="produtos/deletar/{{$produto->id}}/{{$imagem->id}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                                                            Remover
                                                        </a>`